# How to correct this warning “condition has length > 1” warning from `if` function"?

Tags: r, csv

I have made a function that read input from file lists and appends it using rbind.

```
dat <- NA
file.names <- list.files(paste(in.path2,"CSV",sep =""))
for(f in file.names){
  file <- paste(in.path2,"CSV/", f, sep = "")
  tmp <- read.csv(file, stringsAsFactors = F, na.strings = c("", " "))

  if (is.na(dat)) {
    dat <- tmp
  } else {
    colnames(tmp) <- colnames(dat)
    dat <- rbind(dat, tmp)
  }
  print(f)
}
```

I am getting this warning:

```
 1: In if (is.na(dat)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.
```

How to correct this?

Comment: We an do this with `ifelse` instead of `if/else`  Looks like you are checking for the NA in the whole dataset.  it returns a logical matrix with `is.na` from the second run.  Can you show a small reproducible example and what you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to not grow your data.frame like that but like this

```
file.names <- list.files(paste(in.path2,"CSV",sep =""))
input_list <- list()
for(f in file.names){
  file <- paste(in.path2,"CSV/", f, sep = "")
  input_list[[f]] <- read.csv(file, stringsAsFactors = F, na.strings = c("", " "))
  print(f)
}
dat <- do.call(rbind, input_list)
```

This is much faster and you do not need to test if dat is.na or not

Comment: Each file has different column names .The rbind is returning error.There are 50 columns in each file having the same meaning but different colnames

Comment: @Shubh `colnames(input_list[[f]]) <- 1:ncol(input_list[[f]])`  in the for loop and at the end `colnames(dat) <- c(your, prefarred, names)`

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with more easily with `lapply` without worrying about the assignment of `NA` and the `if/else` clauses

```
filenames <- list.files(paste0(in.path2,"CSV"), full.names = TRUE)
do.call(rbind,lapply(filenames, read.csv, na.strings = c("", " "), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

---

Or another option is `fread` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(filenames, fread, na.strings = c("", " ")), fill = TRUE)
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(filenames, read_csv, na = c("", " "))
```

If the columns are not the same, then

```
map(filenames, read_csv, na = c("", " ")) %>%
      bind_rows
```

Comment: I think you forgot the "CSV/", in your paste :-)

Comment: @Linus Thanks, you are right.  I think the OP used it in two places, where it is not needed, if `full.names = TRUE`